# Do you have to attend group meetings for EI in Canada if you found employment and does this have an impact on future EI claims?

Tags: canada, employment-insurance

Do you have to attend group meetings for EI in Canada if you found employment and does this have an impact on future EI claims?

Received a letter from the provincial government to participate in a group meeting to find employment, but I got a job 4 months ago, and I stopped sending EI reports and sent them a report that I found an employment through the EI website, so I am wondering if not going to it can have any impact on future EI claims. I think it might have been a scam, because one of the numbers tell me to leave a message with my name and my social insurance number, which I will never give over the phone.

Comment: First let me check that you are no longer claiming EI? You should only be claiming EI if you aren't working (unless the job you found is part time). Did the letter say you *had* to attend?

Comment: I stopped reporting and I reported that I found employment, and I am pretty sure I didn't receive money, so it sounds like a scam. The letters says I may lose my benefit, but I ended it when I found employment.

Comment: "Pretty sure" you aren't still receiving benefit money? For Pete's sake go and check.

Comment: I would have noticed it if I received money from them, because my earnings would have been a lot higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this sounds like a scam. If you stopped receiving EI you are not going to be required to attend any kind of group classes. EI don't waste their time telling people who have a job how to get one. Them asking for your SIN up front just makes it extra certain.

If there is any doubt talk to the EI office, on a regular number, ignoring any given in the email.